# Pandoc beamer change "Section 1" to "Chapter 1"

Tags: latex, rename, pandoc, beamer

I was doing my thesis presentation and my guide insists that the "Section {1, 2, ..}" should be replaced with "Chapter {1, 2, ..}" as in below image.

[image: Screenshot of "Section 1" that has to be replaced with "Chapter 1"]

I tried a few tricks in YAML, and ended up with the below lines I think would help, but no use.

```yaml
slide-level: 2
top-level-division: chapter
```

My LaTex skills a Level 2/10 but willing to dive deep if needed.

Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
\def\sectionname{Chapter}
```

to your header-includes

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! This was a life-saver. Got it exactly as needed!

Comment: @AdrineCorreya You're welcome! I would also suggest to remove `top-level-division: chapter`. No idea what rmarkdown will do with this, but beamer does not have chapters, so I think not using this might be safer

Comment: I know. I had no clue, and so tried random things.